# how to configure PHPMY ADMIN with Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I need to configure PHPMyAdmin in the docker-compose.yml file ?
How I did this, Can anyone help me out from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying and what is the problem you're seeing? Have you followed the phpMyAdmin documentation for this and which part is causing problems?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch i think my question is clear. "How i include the phomyadmin midule in docer. Yes.. i filowed the dicumentation. But it not works for me. Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying and what is the part you’re having trouble with? What is the error message you’re seeing?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Thanks for your valuable response. I can find my mistake and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of my past project which used **mysql** and **phpadmin**.

Don't forget to replace variables which your own settings.

```bash
version: '3.5'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.2
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
          - "8001:80"
        networks:
          internal:
            ipv4_address: 172.2.0.3
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=db
          - PMA_USER=${DB_USER}
          - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
          - PMA_PORT=3306
        volumes:
          - phpmyadmin:/sessions

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.2.0.0/16

volumes:
    phpmyadmin:
        name: phpmyadmin_data
```